# Client side mobile validation in magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, validation

I added one field of mobile number in **`customer/account/create`** form. I want to put validation in mobile field which allow 10 digit mobile number format . If mobile number format is not valid then display error message as per email id validation.

As per mention in image i want to display error message for mobile number validation.

How to apply client side validation for mobile number?

Please help me...

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento the validation is done through validation.js

```
lib/web/mage/validation.js
```

In this file you will find a number of validation functions.

Now lets see how you can apply validation to your field.
Lets take an example of postcode field. If you look at the code in checkout_index_index.xml you will see there is a node called validation. You can add multiple validation this way like I have added `alphanumeric`.

```
 <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
            <item name="alphanumeric" xsi:type="string">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Function is defined in validation.js like this.

```
"alphanumeric": [
            function (value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);
            },
            'Letters, numbers, spaces or underscores only please'
        ],
```

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:
Add your custom function in this file:

```
app/code/[Vendor]/[ThemName]/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js
```

like this

```
mobilelimitdigit": [
        function(value) {
            return value.length > 9 &&  value.length < 11 
            && value.match(/^\d{10}$/);
        },
        $.mage.__('Please specify a valid 10 digits mobile number')
    ],
```

Comment: Please read question. I want to mobile number validation. 10 digit number can enter only...Letters and Underscores not allow in this field.

Comment: Yes off course. That was just an example of how you can add validation for a field. For mobile number you can add your own function or use the one from the available functions.

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: You can also use "validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10"

Comment: "validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10" this class is not working :( . can i override rules.js in my custom module?

Comment: I am not sure how you can override rules.js in custom module. Sorry.